# Excel formula to remove comma, spaces, period and add a text

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula, concatenation

**Context**

I have data like this:

> Reyes, Ma. Luisa Jun-Oh, Junee Carter, John Jr.

I need to use a combination of excel formulas in one cell to remove commas, periods, spaces and replace with underscore.  Also need to add text after the names (to be used as PDF filename).

**Expected output**

> Reyes_MaLuisa_Text123; JunOh_Junee_Text123; Carter_JohnJr_Text 123 (no
> period and trailing space removed)

**What I've tried**

> Formula used: =REPLACE(I2,FIND(", ",I2,1),2,"_") & "_Text123"  where I
> is the name field.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there. I'm not sure that a series of formulas is the way to go. Have you looked into VBA?

Comment: What version of Excel? Do you also want hyphens removed (not mentioned in your description but missing in your expected output).  How, exactly, are you defining your `name field` Can you use VBA?  In your expected output, is the space in `Text 123` at the end a typo?  Or do you really want that space to be there?

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTITUTE it is easy to use

```
=SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE(I2,",","_") ," ","_")
```